# Does soy milk help prevent cancer?

Tags: cancer, lasting-effects-duration, milk, soy

In [this TED Talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/william_li) the speaker describes the anti-angiogenic properties of soy extract for cancer prevention. I am lactose intolerant, so I was about to give soy milk a try anyway, but I'm wondering how much soy extract is there in normal commercially available soy milk? And, are there some side effects I should be aware of when it comes to drinking soy milk on a regularly basis as a substitute for cow milk?

Comment: Define extract.  What are the relevant chemical compounds?

Comment: @jiggunjer that's a good question, they talk in the video about soy beams and soy extract, but don't say what component is the one to look for in soy.

Comment: According to wikipedia soy milk is simply dried soybeans ground in water, so there really isn't any "extract" to it. It's just liquid soy beans.

Comment: Note that "compound X has anti-angiogenic properties" does not mean "consuming some amount of compound X in food will prevent you from getting cancer". Cancer is much more complicated than that. So even if you knew exactly how much there is in the milk (and it's unlikely that each milk will have the same amount of whichever compound is relevant, if that's even known), this is no good decision criterion for drinking or not drinking soy milk.